# Size of Map in this code

Tags: c++

```
string fn1(string w){
  string result;
  for (auto ele : w)
    if(isalnum(ele))
      result += tolower(ele);   
return result;
}

int main () {
    map<string, long> mp;
    string line, word;
    istringstream iss;
    ifstream f_in("text.txt");
    while (getline(f_in, line)){
       iss.str(line);
       iss >> word;
       word = fn1(word);
       mp[word] += 1;
}
```

Text File:

```
This is a test.
This is only a test.
Do not pass go.
Do not collect $200.
Have a nice day.
```

Why is the size of this map 3?  I thought it would be 14, counting every word in the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the size of this map 3?

The lines

```
   iss.str(line);
   iss >> word;
   word = fn1(word);
   mp[word] += 1;
```

only grab the first word of a line and add it to the map. If you look at the first words of the text file, you only have three unique words.

> I thought it would be 14, counting every word in the text file.

Try this:

```
int main () {
   map<string, long> mp;
   string line, word;
   ifstream f_in("text.txt");
   while (getline(f_in, line)){

      // Construct this object inside the loop.
      // You don't need it outside this loop.
      istringstream iss(line);
      while ( iss >> word )
      {
         word = fn1(word);
         mp[word] += 1;
      }
   }
   std::cout << mp.size() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```